# How to re-authenticate when using ServiceStack server events without prompting for credentials again?

Tags: servicestack

I am developing a proof of concept application demonstrating the use of Server Events using ServiceStack. In this application, all operations have to be done by an authenticated user and I have implemented my own auth provider based on CredentialsAuthProvider.

The application also requires that clients join and leave channels at will. Because of how server events work, this means that every time a client joins a new channel or leaves an existing channel a new instance of ServerEventsClient is created.

This creates a problem for me in that when the new instance of ServerEventsClient is created, it is no longer authorised, and at this point I do not have the credentials to authorise it again and it would be inconvenient to ask the client for these once more.

What is the appropriate solution for this issue? How can I re-authenticate or persist the session information between server events client connections?

Or, is there a way for clients to join / leave channels without having to re-create the connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to transfer the ServiceStack's [ss-id/ss-pid Session Cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) from the old ServerEventClient ServiceClient to the new client which you should be able to do by manually copying the cookies (e.g. using the `GetCookieValues()/SetCookie()`) or re-assigning the entire CookieContainer, e.g:

```
var oldClient = (JsonServiceClient)sseOld.ServiceClient;    
((JsonServiceClient)sseNew.ServiceClient).CookieContainer = sseOld.CookieContainer;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. One way I found that works was to just change the Channels and EventStreamUri properties of the ServerEventsClient class to add the channel and call Restart(). Do you see any problems with that approach? Thanks!

Comment: @Ceottaki yep, that should do it as well. Though I should probably expose a more specific API to call that does this.